# org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: could not deserialize;

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am getting the following error

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

All my classes implements serializable.
Acutally I am fetching one list from DB and using it's value to fetch another result.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace? That will help us to determine the issue more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got Solution :

In one of my POJO there was field whose dataType was Serializabel(as it was nvarchar in DB) so change it to byte[] and problem was solved.

Comment: could you explain more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is not only implementing `Serializable`. There are many other things you have to be aware of. Without a stack trace or some code, we really can't find out what's going wrong. Here are some pointers:

- Sun Java Tutorial: [Persistence](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpy.html)
- [Discover the secrets of the Java Serialization API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/)

Also, as always:

Read [Effective Java by Joshua Bloch](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective), it contains a whole chapter on Serialization.

Comment: All of the links you provided are broken. Could you please provide another one where I can go and read what the solution is?

Comment: @WowBow One link was broken, but it just took one quick Google to get the correct link. The others work, and my answer was posted one and a half years ago.